# I have an error in Laravel logs : cURL error 56: Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT while trying to post on tumblr from my app

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, tumblr

While I am trying to post on Tumblr blog from my Laravel App, I Get This error

```
https://exampleblog.tumblr.com/ : cURL error 56: Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) - /home/seopri721/seoprime/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:201 response null
```

I don't know even what to share here. Just ask me what you need to help me
I got stuck with it. I need your experience and ideas about this guys. Thanks

Comment: Share please the code of CurlFactory.php where line 201 is showing the error

Comment: Mainly these kind of problems happens due to authentication credentials

Comment: it is what it says handle the exception of 407 from the response side, when it is 20x then only you have a return success